# Align checkbox in custom manner

Tags: java, swt

I want to align my checkbox in a way that I have space between the text and checkbox

Eg:

```
Text[ ] should be Text    [ ]
```

Also, there are other widgets below the check box and I want all of them to be properly aligned.

For Eg:

```
Text                [    ]
ListViewer      [    ]
```

Ps: I tried adding space to the button name itself, but the checkbox gets cropped out.

Comment: Swing and SWT are completely different GUI systems, which one is this question about?

Comment: It is a SWT question

Comment: You would have to use a separate `Label` and check box `Button` (with not text) to achieve that. Alignment is done using layouts.

Answer (score 0):

To have the text on the left you would need to use a separate `Label` control.

Using a `GridLayout` for your `Composite` it might be something like;

```java
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label label1 = new Label(composite, SWT.LEAD);
label1.setText("Text");

Button button1 = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);

Label label2 = new Label(composite, SWT.LEAD);
label2.setText("ListViewer");

Button button2 = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
```